# How to assign UserProfile with WishList without using a default user

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have an app that contains a model UserProfile()

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

connecting to a default user(User). I wanted to connect my user with a wishlist model

```
class WishList(models.Model):
    toy_name_wish = models.ForeignKey(Toy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_wish = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_wish
```

And using generic view with `def post(self, request):` I created simple logic for a toy that will be shown in admin part as a user's wish item

```
class DetailToyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/detail_toy.html'
    #other defs

    def post(self, request, toy_id):
        toy = get_object_or_404(Toy, pk=toy_id)
        user_profile = UserProfile()
        wishlist = WishList() 
        try:
            selected_toy = get_object_or_404(Toy, pk=toy_id) 
    except(KeyError, Toy.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'app/detail_toy.html', {'toy': toy})
    else:
        user_profile.user = self.request.user
        user = user_profile.user
        wishlist.toy_name_wish = toy
        wishlist.user_wish = user
        wishlist.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:detail-category-toy', args=(toy.id,)))
```

If it's important here's my urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'), # INDEX
    path('personal-page/', views.personal_page, name='personal-page'),
    # SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT AND SIGN_UP
    path('sign-in/', auth_views.login,
        {'template_name': 'app/sign_in.html'},
        name='sign-in'),
    path('sign-out/', auth_views.logout,
        {'next_page': '/'},
        name='sign-out'),
    path('sign-up/', views.sign_up, name='sign-up'),
    # DETAIL_PAGES
    #url(r'^book-detail/(?P<book>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail_book, name='book'),
    url(r'^detail_category_toy/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail_category_toy, name='detail-category-toy'),
    url(r'^detail-toy/(?P<toy_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailToyView.as_view(), name='toy')]
```

So here is the problem when I click on the button I'm getting an error

```
ValueError at /detail-toy/2/
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>": "WishList.user_wish" must be a "UserProfile" instance.
```

This means I cannot use user.username 
So how do I get UserProfile instance instead of the basic User model?

P.S: Sorry for some stupid-called variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your immediate problem is that you are setting a User to the WishList object rather than a UserProfile. The line before the save should be:

```
wishlist.user_wish = user_profile
```

But really there are a lot of odd things going on here. A user can only have a single UserProfile, which sounds right, but in this view you always create a new one; if that user already has a profile, this will cause an error. And your WishList model is not really a list, but a single relationship between a profile and a toy.

What you actually need here is a many-to-many relationship between UserProfile and Toy, which is the wishlist:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
    wishlist = models.ManyToManyField('Toy')
```

(and you don't need the WishList model at all)

And in your view, use `get_or_create` to either get the existing profile or create a new one:

```
def post(self, request, toy_id):
    toy = get_object_or_404(Toy, pk=toy_id)
    user_profile = get_or_create(UserProfile, user=request.user)
    user_profile.wishlist.add(toy)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:detail-category-toy', args=(toy.id,)))
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot